# Trying to add attacment " csv file " to gmail without success , Its Android App , im debugging with my phone as emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

the app opens gmail and put all the data in but don't bring the attachment and I don't see issues.

**Here is the code :**

```
            String filelocation = root.getAbsolutePath() + filename;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            String message = "File to be shared is " + filename + ".";
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filelocation));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:xyz@gmail.com"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("is exception raises during sending mail" + e);
        }
```

I also uploaded image .

Thanks in advance .

[image: added Image preview]

Comment: `Uri.parse("file://" + filelocation))` That will not do. Use a FileProvider to serve your file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access the file using Provider :

Add a provider in your manifest under `</application>`

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="@string/authority" //<string name="authority">'<packagename>'.provider</string>  
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

and create a Path xml under res/xml/file_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

then try to access the file using provider

```
Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            this.getPackageName().toString() + ".provider",
            image_FilePath
        );

Intent i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share:"));
```

Hope its works ...